# R Shiny Single Plot to Fill Entire Dashboard Page

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have built a single plot that I would like to fill the entire page of a Shiny dashboard. Basically the below code is working for me except that the chart is always half the height of the page, and I would like it to fill the full height. I have tried using the fillPage() function and other solutions on this forum, but none seem to work for my particular situation.

Below is some reproducible code and an image of what it produces. Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Header"),

    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(),
    body <- dashboardBody(
        fillPage(plotlyOutput("Waterfall", height="100%", width="100%"))
    ),
    dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title="Title"), sidebar,body)
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
  x= list("Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "Purchases", "Other expenses", "Profit before tax")
  measure= c("relative", "relative", "total", "relative", "relative", "total")
  text= c("+60", "+80", "", "-40", "-20", "Total")
  y= c(60, 80, 0, -40, -20, 0)
  data = data.frame(x=factor(x,levels=x),measure,text,y)
  
  output$Waterfall <- renderPlotly({ plot_ly(
    data, name = "20", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
    x = ~x, textposition = "outside", y= ~y, text =~text,
    connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)")))   })
})
  
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[Fill Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHD0P.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a CSS line

```
tags$style(type = "text/css", "#Waterfall {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
```

**Edit:** if you need to change all plotly plots, use this instead:

```
tags$style(type = "text/css", ".plotly {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}")
```

in this section

```
 fillPage(
      tags$style(type = "text/css", "#Waterfall {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
      plotlyOutput("Waterfall", height="100%", width="100%"))
  ),
```

This should work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Header"),
  
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(),
  body <- dashboardBody(
    fillPage(
      tags$style(type = "text/css", "#Waterfall {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
      plotlyOutput("Waterfall", height="100%", width="100%"))
  ),
  dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title="Title"), sidebar,body)
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  x= list("Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "Purchases", "Other expenses", "Profit before tax")
  measure= c("relative", "relative", "total", "relative", "relative", "total")
  text= c("+60", "+80", "", "-40", "-20", "Total")
  y= c(60, 80, 0, -40, -20, 0)
  data = data.frame(x=factor(x,levels=x),measure,text,y)
  
  output$Waterfall <- renderPlotly({ plot_ly(
    data, name = "20", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
    x = ~x, textposition = "outside", y= ~y, text =~text,
    connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)")))   })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Similar question: [Basic example of fillPage in Shiny - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096375/basic-example-of-fillpage-in-shiny-how-does-it-work)

Comment: You're a champ! That did the job. You know, I had seen another posting on here where the solution was that very same line of code you added, but it wasn't clear that it needed to go inside the fillPage function. That was the key. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know it worked :) Your plot looks great by the way.

Comment: Hi, what to do if I have multiple tabs and in each tab I have plots that I want to view in maximum screen?

Comment: @AhsanHimel, you can replace `#Waterfall` with `.plotly` like this:
`tags$style(type = "text/css", ".plotly {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}")`

Comment: `#Waterfall` targets only plot from `output$Waterfall`. But `.plotly` will target all plotly plots