# How do I make my R Shiny dashboard fill the window?

Tags: css, r, user-interface, shiny, publish

I am trying to create an interactive database for recipes in Shiny to provide an easy way to search my books. I have a functioning table with controls which works and looks good whenever running either within VS Code or RStudio, but whenever I publish it to ShinyApps.io it only occupies a tiny portion of the screen:

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk9Pm.png)

I've tried including a style.css file with this information:

```
/***CONTAINER SIZING***/ 

.main-container{
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    max-width: 99% !important;
    /* overflow-y: visible !important; */
    /* height: 1000px !important; */
    /* margin-top: 0px !important; */
    /* margin-bottom: 0px !important; */
    /* max-height: 99% !important; */
    /* min-height: 99% !important; */
}
```

I've tried various combinations of the commented out lines to no effect, but the top 3 lines have made it fill it widthways.

I also tried running [this code I found of someone seemingly having a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096375/basic-example-of-fillpage-in-shiny-how-does-it-work), but it has the same issue; fills only a tiny box in the window. The picture is me trying it with my table, but it has the same issue unmodified.

[Other code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAiSU.png)

Is there something I'm missing? I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: Try: `options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)`

Comment: @TarJae tried including this within my server function but no effect. Some googling implies that it's for upload/download sizes, rather than page sizes, so not sure how to use this as I'm not working with download/upload functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

`shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(height = 1300))`

In answer to your comment, I am not entirely sure.. sorry. You might be able to try wrapping the entire app within the bounds of a div. You can mess around with the specific width and height parameters.

```
<div style="width:1000px;height:1300px">
{r}
Your code.....
shinyApp(ui, server)
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This has mostly worked - the dashboard is now seemingly set to 1200 pixels. However, this still seems to be independent of the window size - when I view my app in a fullscreen window, it looks okay as there is only one scrollbar which seems to control the frame the dashboard is in, but when the window is smaller there are two, one for the window holding the frame and one for the frame.

[Image](https://imgur.com/a/MkgUk1k).

Is there a way to have the the frame effectively BE the window?